# Radix sort won't work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, radix-sort

I'm currently writing a program to compare how long in milliseconds a MSD radix sort takes compared to QuicksSort using Arrays.sort(array).

If the input in the radix sort isn't that big, it works as supposed. But if I increase the input, the algorithm will suddenly take forever to complete. I have no idea why this i happening, and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I know for a fact that quicksort is slower for larger arrays compared to radix sort, and this program just works in the opposite direction for some reason (quicksorts becomes faster, radix sort slower).

At this point I feel I have tried everything to find an answer for this problem, but I just can't seem to find what's wrong at all.

Here's the code:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class RadixSort{

  final static int NUM_BIT = 9;
  final static int MIN_NUM = 31;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Random random = new Random();
    RadixSort mainObject = new RadixSort();


    int n = 100;
    double time = 0;
    double quicktime = 0;

    while(n != 10000000){

      int[] a = new int[n];
      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        a[i] = random.nextInt(a.length);
      }

      time = mainObject.VRadixMulti(a);
      quicktime = mainObject.quickSort(a);

       System.out.println("\nQuicksort time for n = " + n + ": " + quicktime);

       System.out.println("RadixSort time for n = " + n + ": " + time);

       n = n*10;
    }
  }



  public double VRadixMulti(int[] a){
    long tt = System.nanoTime();
    int numBit = 0;
    int[] b = new int[a.length];


    int max = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
      if(a[i] > max){
        max = a[i];
      }
    }

    while(max >=1 << numBit){numBit++;}
    LeftRadix(a, b, 0, a.length, numBit, NUM_BIT);


    double time = (System.nanoTime()- tt)/1000000.0;
    testSort(a);
    return time;
  }


  public void LeftRadix(int[] a, int[] b, int left, int right, int leftSortBit, int maskLen){
    int mask = (1<<maskLen)-1;
    int shift = leftSortBit-maskLen;
    int acumVal = 0, j;
    int[] count = new int[mask+1];


    if(shift < 0){
      mask = (1<<maskLen)-1;
      shift = 0;
    }

    for(int i = left; i < right; i++){
      count[(a[i]>> shift) & mask]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= mask; i++){
      j = count[i];
      count[i] = acumVal;
      acumVal += j;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      b[count[(a[i]>>shift) & mask]++] = a[i];
    }

    int startIndex = left;
    int prevDig = (b[left] >> shift) & mask;

    if(shift >= 0){
      for(int i = left; i < right; i++){
        int val = (b[i] >> shift) & mask;

        if(i == right-1){
          if(i - startIndex <= NUM_BIT){
            insertSort(b, startIndex, i);
          } else {
            LeftRadix(b, a, startIndex, i, leftSortBit-maskLen, maskLen);
          }
        }

        if(val != prevDig){
          if(i-startIndex <= 1){
            prevDig = val;
            continue;
          }

          if(i - startIndex <= NUM_BIT){
            insertSort(b, startIndex, i);
          } else {
            LeftRadix(b, a, startIndex, i, leftSortBit-maskLen, maskLen);
          }
          startIndex = i;
        }
        prevDig = val;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      a[i] = b[i];
    }
  }


  public void insertSort(int[] array, int left, int right){
    int temp;


    for(int i = 1; i < right; i++){
      for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
        if(array[i] < array[i-1]){
          temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j-1];
          array[j-1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public double quickSort(int[] a){
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    double time = (System.nanoTime()- time)/1000000.0;
    return time;
  }


  public void testSort(int[] a){
    for (int i = 0; i< a.length-1;i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i+1]){
        System.out.println("SorteringsFEIL på: "+
        i +" a["+i+"]:"+a[i]+" > a["+(i+1)+"]:"+a[i+1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `Arrays.sort()` is quick sort? Take a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html At least for efficient implementations, quick sort is not stable and probably is not used as the `Arrays.sort()` algorithm.

Comment: According to this Arrays.sort() is a quicksort method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])

Comment: It is not the `traditional` quick sort, since it uses dual pivots. By the way, your radix sort seems over complicated...

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't really affect the program overral, the quicksort method works fine.

Comment: Would you consider using a LSD Radix sort? You may also want to consider using a fixed base value like 256 (8 bits), which would take 4 passes for 32 bit integers. For signed integers (assuming two's complement), you can complement the sign bit when using the most significant byte for indexing.